# Rust pointer deference with vectors

Tags: rust

I am stuck why the println on is `*p1.offset(0)` is giving me 0. Any ideas?

```
fn main() {
        let p1 : *const u8 = vec![17u8,2u8].as_ptr();
        let p2 : *const u8 = "123".as_ptr();
        
        unsafe{
        println!("{}", *p1.offset(0) as u8);//should get 17, but I get 0
        println!("{}", *p2.offset(0) as char);
        }
}
```

Here is the link to playground. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=18222645e5fa43cde787659402962be3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointers do not own the things they point at, so when you do this:

```
let p1 : *const u8 = vec![17u8,2u8].as_ptr();
```

the sequence of events that occurs is:

- A `Vec` is constructed, with a buffer allocated on the heap
- `as_ptr()` is called, returning a pointer to the buffer
- The `Vec` is dropped, because there is nothing owning it, so the buffer is deallocated
- When you later dereference the pointer, you are invoking Undefined Behavior

The second case works correctly:

```
let p2 : *const u8 = "123".as_ptr();
```

because "123" is a string literal, and string literals have `'static` lifetime - they last as long as the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version.

```
fn main() {
        let data = vec![17u8,2u8];
        let p1 : *const u8 = data.as_ptr();
        let p2 : *const u8 = "123".as_ptr();
        
        unsafe{
        println!("{}", *p1.offset(0) as u8); // not get 17 instead of 0
        println!("{}", *p2.offset(0) as char);
        }
}
```

I don't know why need to extract vec to separate variable